# Python (PyQt5) version of Qt Callout Example

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, qtcharts

### Callout Example

> From QtCharts package: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-callout-example.html
>
> This (excellent) example shows how to draw an additional element (a callout) on top of the chart.

The question is if this example can be found somewhere implemented in python?
[image: example_screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for this example ported to PyQt5 (python), but didn't found any. So I wrote it by myself and would like to share it with you (just to save your time). It's written for Python 3.8, but should work for older ones as well, PyQt version is 5.14.1.

There is just a little difference against the original C++ implementation. `QGraphicsScene` has to be explicitly set - in `View` constructor class and Each new `Callout` object has to be explicitly added to the scene. Frankly I don't know why but I don't care. Exactly the same Qt library version in C++ doesn't require that.

```py
import sys
from typing import List

from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QLineSeries, QSplineSeries
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF, QRect, QRectF, QSizeF, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont, QFontMetrics, QMouseEvent, QPainter, QPainterPath, QResizeEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent, \
    QGraphicsSimpleTextItem, QGraphicsView, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, QWidget


class Callout(QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self, parent: QChart):
        super().__init__()
        self.m_chart: QChart = parent
        self.m_text: str = ''
        self.m_anchor: QPointF = QPointF()
        self.m_font: QFont = QFont()
        self.m_textRect: QRectF = QRectF()
        self.m_rect: QRectF = QRectF()

    def setText(self, text: str):
        self.m_text = text
        metrics = QFontMetrics(self.m_font)
        self.m_textRect = QRectF(metrics.boundingRect(QRect(0, 0, 150, 150), Qt.AlignLeft, self.m_text))
        self.m_textRect.translate(5, 5)
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        self.m_rect = QRectF(self.m_textRect.adjusted(-5, -5, 5, 5))
        self.updateGeometry()

    def updateGeometry(self):
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        self.setPos(self.m_chart.mapToPosition(self.m_anchor) + QPointF(10, -50))

    def boundingRect(self) -> QRectF:
        from_parent = self.mapFromParent(self.m_chart.mapToPosition(self.m_anchor))
        anchor = QPointF(from_parent)
        rect = QRectF()
        rect.setLeft(min(self.m_rect.left(), anchor.x()))
        rect.setRight(max(self.m_rect.right(), anchor.x()))
        rect.setTop(min(self.m_rect.top(), anchor.y()))
        rect.setBottom(max(self.m_rect.bottom(), anchor.y()))
        return rect

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option: QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget: QWidget):
        path = QPainterPath()
        mr = self.m_rect
        path.addRoundedRect(mr, 5, 5)

        anchor = QPointF(self.mapFromParent(self.m_chart.mapToPosition(self.m_anchor)))
        if not mr.contains(anchor):
            point1 = QPointF()
            point2 = QPointF()

            # establish the position of the anchor point in relation to self.m_rect
            above = anchor.y() <= mr.top()
            above_center = mr.top() < anchor.y() <= mr.center().y()
            below_center = mr.center().y() < anchor.y() <= mr.bottom()
            below = anchor.y() > mr.bottom()

            on_left = anchor.x() <= mr.left()
            left_of_center = mr.left() < anchor.x() <= mr.center().x()
            right_of_center = mr.center().x() < anchor.x() <= mr.right()
            on_right = anchor.x() > mr.right()

            # get the nearest self.m_rect corner.
            x = (on_right + right_of_center) * mr.width()
            y = (below + below_center) * mr.height()
            corner_case = (above and on_left) or (above and on_right) or (below and on_left) or (below and on_right)
            vertical = abs(anchor.x() - x) > abs(anchor.y() - y)
            horizontal = bool(not vertical)

            x1 = x + left_of_center * 10 - right_of_center * 20 + corner_case * horizontal * (
                    on_left * 10 - on_right * 20)
            y1 = y + above_center * 10 - below_center * 20 + corner_case * vertical * (above * 10 - below * 20)
            point1.setX(x1)
            point1.setY(y1)

            x2 = x + left_of_center * 20 - right_of_center * 10 + corner_case * horizontal * (
                    on_left * 20 - on_right * 10)
            y2 = y + above_center * 20 - below_center * 10 + corner_case * vertical * (above * 20 - below * 10)
            point2.setX(x2)
            point2.setY(y2)

            path.moveTo(point1)
            path.lineTo(anchor)
            path.lineTo(point2)
            path = path.simplified()

        painter.setPen(QColor(30, 30, 30))
        painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        painter.drawPath(path)
        painter.drawText(self.m_textRect, self.m_text)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent):
        event.setAccepted(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setPos(self.mapToParent(event.pos() - event.buttonDownPos(Qt.LeftButton)))
            event.setAccepted(True)
        else:
            event.setAccepted(False)


class View(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.m_callouts: List[Callout] = []
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        # chart
        self.m_chart = QChart(parent)
        self.m_chart.setMinimumSize(640, 480)
        self.m_chart.setTitle("Hover the line to show callout. Click the line to make it stay")
        self.m_chart.legend().hide()
        series = QLineSeries()
        series.append(1, 3)
        series.append(4, 5)
        series.append(5, 4.5)
        series.append(7, 1)
        series.append(11, 2)
        self.m_chart.addSeries(series)

        series2 = QSplineSeries()
        series2.append(1.6, 1.4)
        series2.append(2.4, 3.5)
        series2.append(3.7, 2.5)
        series2.append(7, 4)
        series2.append(10, 2)
        self.m_chart.addSeries(series2)

        self.m_chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self.m_chart.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
        self.scene().addItem(self.m_chart)

        self.m_coordX = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(self.m_chart)
        self.m_coordX.setPos(self.m_chart.size().width() / 2 - 50, self.m_chart.size().height() - 20)
        self.m_coordX.setText("X: ")
        self.m_coordY = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(self.m_chart)
        self.m_coordY.setPos(self.m_chart.size().width() / 2 + 50, self.m_chart.size().height() - 20)
        self.m_coordY.setText("Y: ")

        self.m_tooltip = Callout(self.m_chart)
        self.scene().addItem(self.m_tooltip)

        series.clicked.connect(self.keep_callout)
        series.hovered.connect(self.tooltip)
        series2.clicked.connect(self.keep_callout)
        series2.hovered.connect(self.tooltip)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent):
        if scene := self.scene():
            scene.setSceneRect(QRectF(QPointF(0, 0), QSizeF(event.size())))
            self.m_chart.resize(QSizeF(event.size()))
            self.m_coordX.setPos(self.m_chart.size().width() / 2 - 50, self.m_chart.size().height() - 20)
            self.m_coordY.setPos(self.m_chart.size().width() / 2 + 50, self.m_chart.size().height() - 20)

            for callout in self.m_callouts:
                callout.updateGeometry()

        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        from_chart = self.m_chart.mapToValue(event.pos())
        self.m_coordX.setText(f"X: {from_chart.x()}")
        self.m_coordX.setText(f"Y: {from_chart.y()}")
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def keep_callout(self):
        self.m_callouts.append(self.m_tooltip)
        self.m_tooltip = Callout(self.m_chart)
        self.scene().addItem(self.m_tooltip)

    def tooltip(self, point: QPointF, state: bool):
        if not self.m_tooltip:
            self.m_tooltip = Callout(self.m_chart)

        if state:
            self.m_tooltip.setText(f"X: {point.x()} \nY: {point.x()} ")
            self.m_tooltip.m_anchor = point
            self.m_tooltip.setZValue(11)
            self.m_tooltip.updateGeometry()
            self.m_tooltip.show()
        else:
            self.m_tooltip.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = View()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```